# In mapstruct "Boolean" parameter in the derived class automatically gets added after mapper class invocation

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper, graphql-java

I am working on spring boot with graphql implementation. And, I am mapping my graphql request parameters to an internal project with help of a map struct. I have written my mapper class where I have mapped my request parameters [source] to the target parameters. Below is the POJO implementation in my target.

Example:

```
public class A extends B implements Serializable {

    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;

}

public class B extends C implements Serializable {
    private String address;
    private String countryIsoCode;
    private Boolean isMapped; 
}

public class C implements Serializable {
    private String empRefNo;
    private ***Boolean exist***;
}
```

Here class "B" and "C" has "Boolean" type parameter added in the POJO. I have mapped all the String parameters in my mapper class and didn't map "Boolean" parameters. But when I invoke my mapper class to map the request parameters, after mapping, my request has "exist" parameter [Boolean type] also added without doing any mapping. But in some cases, "isMapped" parameter which is also of type "Boolean" is not been added in the request. When I change the data type of the "exist" parameter to "String", it is not getting added to the request after the mapper class invocation.

Mapstruct automatically adds the "Boolean" type parameter in request from class "C" without mapping. Can someone please help me with this, Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide code actually showing the problem?

Comment: Provide your mapper class, and what is getting added?